# How to export an excel file with different sheets in R?

Tags: r

I can export a data frame as an excel book using `write_xlsx()`, however I have to export several hundred files each one with 5 sheets. Is there a way to take 5 data frames and export them to a single excel book in which each data frame is in a sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the package `openxlsx` which allows manipulation of an excel book / excel sheets including formatting. Simple example to only write data is below.

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()    
addWorksheet(wb, "test1")    
writeData(wb, "test1", mtcars)    
addWorksheet(wb, "test2")    
writeData(wb, "test2", mtcars)   
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx")
```